# Swift Story board inside the tableview issue

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

May i know the what is this design viewController inside the tableview.
[which type of this code like container view or etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcYrr.png)

Comment: UITableView over UIView.

Comment: This is the way how you can have a `tableview` object in your `view controller` which is not added to the `view controller's view` yet using Storyboard.

Comment: This short tutorial can help you to understand. https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/interface-builder-scene-dock-extra-views-26cef5fe363b

Comment: How do questions like this get upvoted?